# Dynamically Change Visual Element's Background Image in Unity UI Builder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I want to add and remove a Visual Element background image from Unity UI Builder using scripting. I know that this line lets you dynamically change the text of a label in UI Builder:

```
name_of_my_UI_Builder_Label.text = "Change Label To This Text";
```

Is there something similar I can do to access my background image here?

Answer (score 4):

```
name_of_my_UI_Builder_Label.style.backgroundImage = new StyleBackground(sprite);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30898135)

Comment: I disagree with the comments above - I think this did in fact answer the question and did not need further explanation. Thanks Kirill!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to do this is,

- Create an image component.
- Add a script in which you can add the sprites that you wish to display as a background.

  ```
   `public Sprite[] sprites;
    public int loadIndex
    private Image image;

    private void Start()
    {
     image = GetComponent<Image>();
     image.sprite = sprites[loadIndex];  
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
visualTree.Q<VisualElement>("TARGET_ELEMENT").style.backgroundImage = new StyleBackground(AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>("Assets/a.png"));
```

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Sprite' to 'UnityEngine.UIElements.StyleBackground'`